# Using webpack with react files called by EJS

Tags: node.js, webpack, ejs

I have a number of .js client files that are referenced by  tags in my EJS views. I want to use webpack for this, so that they are referenced by require('x.js') instead.

I don't understand how to do this. I'm using ejs-simple-loader but it's not working.

I guess I need to scan the .ejs files for the references to the .js files, and bundle the required js libraries, but *not* bundle the EJS files (as they are dynamically generating web content obvs!). Shouldn't be rocket science should it?!

EDIT: Currently ejs-simple-loader config (which I think is wrong - I need to scan EJS files for inclusion of their dependencies, but not the EJS files?)

```
        {
            test: /\.ejs$/,
            include: [/src/],
            exclude: [/node_modules/],
            use: [
                {loader: 'ejs-simple-loader'}
            ]
        },
```

Comment: can you provide more detail about how you use ejs-simple-loader ?

Comment: I guess that's kind of my question :) ATM I have it scanning .ejs files, but not sure if that's right because surely that will try to include them in the bundle? I'll edit the question with the current ejs-simple-loader config which is surely wrong...